# three.js increases file size?

Tags: three.js, maya, filesize

I just downloaded MayaThreeExporter and I wanted to export out just a model from maya. I imported an obj file which is 34 MB into maya and try to export out a three.js file, with out adding textures or lights. But every time I do that, the size of the three.js file goes up to 77MB. More than double. Can someone please help me understand why it would increase the file size? or is there a way to reduce the size?

Comment: it is possible that Maya creates some additional data. e.g. if you import a mesh without normals, these are created automatically and if you export it again, you will have additional data. But the easiest way is to try to import a very simple object like a box or a plane, export it as three.js and have a look at the files. Since both are ascii files, the difference should be easy to see.

Comment: Also note, the three.js Maya exporter has been deleted from the project. three.js can load OBJ, FBX, and other formats Maya can create, which were determined to be more reliable than the three.js Maya exporter.

Comment: More than likely it's string float length difference The maya exporter has a static value of 8. However, also, If your UV option is on during export, then you're going to be exporting UVs even if you have no textures. This can easily add a second set of vector3 values to your resulting json, doubling the size.

Comment: Thank you so much guys for getting back and yes, I turned off the export normal option and the file size dropped dramatically, which is fantastic. Now I just need to work out the best way possible to export textures and shaders with this model. Not sure if baking the textures in maya would do the job. Any suggestions?
Thank you
Rahul